# Terminology for a phrase that changes meaning over time within a closed community

Tags: terminology, semantics, language-change, pragmatics, discourse-analysis

I am looking for the linguistic terminology for the phenomenon of semantic change in a discourse within a closed community. This closed community could be a couple, a company etc.

For example, imagine the following scenario. Employees in a company complain about lack of equipment, e.g. printers. They initially just want additional printers. The managers don't do anything about it. The employees again complain about the lack of printers, and the circle continues. However, at some point the complaint about lack of printers starts to shift its meaning from "we don't have enough printers" to "management doesn't listen to us", "management don't care" etc.

I'm thinking about a similar scenario in a romantic relationship where complaints such as "you always leave the light on", or "you never wash the dishes" is used in a similar way to express something deeper.

Is there a terminology in linguistics that would describe these scenarios? I was thinking about polysemy/metonymy but don't think it describes this properly.

Comment: My first thought is "intertextuality", in that the meaning of "we don't have printers" in context depends on the previous events. But since there are no "texts" involved I feel there should be a better word for it.

Comment: Jargon polysemy maybe :)